# Allow Role to edit Custom Node Type

Tags: 6, users

This is for Drupal 6.

I have a module that creates a custom node type called program.
I have a role called "marketing" and it has a permission entitled "edit marketing copy"

I've used hook_access to grant update permissions to users who meet this criteria, but the edit tab does not appear on the content when I view it.

```
function programs_access($op, $node, $account) {
    switch($op) {
        case 'update':
            if(user_access('administer programs', $account) || user_access('edit marketing copy', $account)) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        case 'delete':
        case 'create':
            if(user_access('administer programs', $account)) return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I know that the user has the permission because the view template shows specific things based on permissions and those work as intended. I just do not receive the "edit tab"

How do I make the edit tab appear on the page for the user? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user has permissions to use that node's input filter.

If that is OK, try rebuilding the content permissions.

Comment: Glad it helped - I was in the same situation quite a few times :)